# Coefficient of greatest term for the polynomial $\cos(n*\arccos(x))$. $\ D_f\ = [-1,1]$ and $n\in N$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, polynomials

I have been able to show with help of induction that $\cos(n*\arccos(x))$ indeed is a polynomial, but I also want to know the coefficient ahead of the greatest term, the answer is $2^n$, but I cannot figure out why this is the case.

$\ D_f\ = [-1,1]$ and $n\in N$.

Comment: How about: write down the first five of these polynomials, then maybe you can see how to prove your conjecture by induction.

Comment: Perhaps you can use induction and the recurrence relation that the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind satisfy.